# Operator expected when using ?X but not when using X?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to get this recursive function to work, but when I have `?` I get `Operator expected` error. If I remove the `?` the program works. Am I misunderstanding how to use `?` or is there some other problem?

Here is the code:

```
f(?X,?Z):-g(X,Z).
f(?X,?Z):-g(X,Y), f(Y,Z).
```

Comment: Why you use `?` ?

Comment: It's an exercise. I think I am misunderstanding it.

Comment: `?` isn't valid syntax in this context. Not sure why you have it there. Sometimes Prolog manuals use it as a way to illustrate whether predicate arguments "output" a value. But just get rid of them in your code. They don't belong there. At some point, you're going to have to define `g/2` (`g` with 2 arguments).